# iOS Custom Notification Action weird behavior add calendar

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

wondering if someone has had any experience with this. So, i have a custom notification action set ( ADDTOCALENDAR ) when the user taps on Add To calendar y runs a code that adds an event to the default calendar.

The weird behavior is :

1- ) if the App is not running . It adds to the calendar Ok right away from the push notification, But...

2-) if the app is already running in the Background (not active in foreground ) it Wont add to the calendar till the user puts the App in the Foreground - Active .

Why if the app is running in background it wont add to the calendar from the push ?

This is happening iOS 10.xx and iOS 11...

Comment: Do you have `content-available` set to `1`? If not your app won't be woke up in the background...and only tapping it or being the foreground when it arrives would make it work

Comment: Hi @Honey  ,  content-available is used for silent notifications. this is a normal notification with an Action,  it show button that adds an Event to the default calendar of the device. it runs the code of the Action Identifier correctly when the App is not running..but when the app is in the background and the user is at the home of the phone en recieves the notification, the action only happens if the user makes pops the app to the foreground making it active...

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your two states. Your 2nd state is obviously _background_ State. Your first state I am not sure what state you mean. Do you mean _Suspended_ state? For states see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Comment: hi @honey, im providing the answer :) be sure to check it out! . about the states i was talking about Background and Active states . im not sure i did explain well in the post.. the thing is if the app was running in the background , the notification custom action didnt run well, it didnt add to the calendar till i put the app in the Foreground (Active state) again.. now.. if the app wasnt running at all... the notification custom action would work perfectly... the problem was the completionHandle() i had it outside of the Block running my stuff to do.. ;) check out the answer ..

Comment: Oh I see, for clarity, can you edit your question and show what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some debugging and checking the code i realized with my two other custom actions i had the CompletionHandler() call outside of the block.

So, first for those who doesnt know, when you have a custom action notification, you make the check for the Category Identifier, then check for the Custom Action Identifier, then process whatever you will and Never forget to call completionHandler() right after.

My problem was i was using a Class service with a function with a block and had the completionHandler outside of the block. Thats why it was doing that weird behavior.

Heres the complete correct code and showing where the error was...

```
// AppDelegate.swif

   // Handling notifications - When in background
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

   // Notifcation Category: Reserve
        if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier == "RESERVE" {
            // Handle the actions for the reserve


                // Action: Approve
            if response.actionIdentifier == "APPROVE" {
                // The user launched the app
                print("Approve")

               // print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
                print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo.description)
                print(response.notification.request.content)

                if let info = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> {
                    // Check if value present before using it

                    let reserveid = info["reserveid"] as? String ?? ""
                    let fecha = info["fecha"] as? String ?? ""
                    let username = info["username"] as? String ?? ""
                    let qty = info["qty"] as? String ?? ""
                    let comentario = info["comentario"] as? String ?? ""
                    let approval = info["approval"] as? String ?? ""
                    let empresa_nombre = info["empresanombre"] as? String ?? ""
                    let direccion = info["direccion"] as? String ?? ""
                    let lat = info["lat"] as? String ?? ""
                    let long = info["long"] as? String ?? ""
                    let telefono = info["tel"] as? String ?? ""
                    let provincia = info["prov"] as? String ?? ""


                    let reserveService = ReserveService()
                    reserveService.process(id: reserveid, approve: true, completion: { (success) in


                        if (success) {

                            let note = "\(empresa_nombre)\n\(direccion) - \(provincia)\n\nReserva de: \(username)\nCantidad de personas: \(qty)\nFecha: \(fecha)\nComentario de cliente: \(comentario)"
                            print(note)
                            let EventServices = EventService.sharedInstance
                            EventServices.startDate = "\(fecha)"
                            EventServices.title = "Reserva de \(username)"
                            EventServices.notes = note
                            EventServices.isRestadmin = true
                            EventServices.lat = lat
                            EventServices.long = long
                            EventServices.direccion = direccion
                            EventServices.provincia = provincia
                            EventServices.emp_nombre = empresa_nombre
                            EventServices.checkCalendarAuthorizationStatusAndAdd()
                           completionHandler() // correct completionHandler Call
                        }
                    })

                }
              //  completionHandler() // had it here mistakenly.
            }

}

}
```